# Recreating a table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using Rails and Postgres. I currently have a Like table created. I need to drop this table and re-create it. Here's what I've done so far.

1) Rename `create_likes` migration file to `create_likes_old` so there is no conflict with file names within migrations.

2) Change the name of the table inside the migration from `create_table :likes` to `create_table :likes_old`.

3) Generate new `create_likes` migration that creates a table called Like.

Currently I'm running into the following issue when I run `rake db:migrate`:

```
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "likes" already exists
```

This makes it seems like the Like table was never renamed to LikeOld. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: This table is already exist in database. You need to drop it or rename. Or not to rename anything but in new migration to drop old table and then recreate it. 2nd way is much better because it is safe for the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old migrations don't run when you change their content, and you *should not rename them*. Even if they did run, changing the `create_table :likes` to `create_table :old_likes` cannot possibly change the name of an existing table. That isn't what `create_table` does. At best, re-running that migration will now cause a new table to be created called `old_likes`, with no content, while leaving your old `likes` table unaffected. In actuality re-running that migration will simply fail, as it will attempt to *undo* the migration first, dropping the table `old_likes` which does not yet exist.

What you need to do is create a new migration called `rename_likes_to_old_likes`, which actually renames the table, using [`rename_table`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html). Then, either:

- delete the old migration entirely, so you can introduce a new migration with the same name

OR

- create a new migration with a unique name such as `create_new_likes_table` or the like, and introduce your new table there.

Comment: I swear that I read a Stackoverflow answer explaining why you can do such a thing and it had 30+ points. I wish I could find it. I honestly believe you. The funny thing is is that my original idea was working at one point but due to a git issue I lost a file or two that blew everything up. I'm glad this is sorted out now.

Comment: "so you can introduce a new migration with the same name" - migration name includes timestamp, so deleting previous one is not necessary, as well as making a unique name.

Comment: @jason328 There might be missing context, but I can tell you with absolute certainty that changing an old migration will have absolutely no effect unless you explicit re-run that migration using `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=<ID of migration>`, and if you try to run that for the migration you describe, it will fail as it will first try to drop a table called `old_likes`, which does not yet exist.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, the string after the digits must be unique. You cannot have a migration called `001_stuff.rb` and `002_stuff.rb`, the `_stuff` must be unique. I invite you try try this yourself.

Comment: Hmm. I blame mongoid and its lack of migrations. I obviously lost contact with reality in this area. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The issue is that the migration name maps directly to the class it defines. `create_stuff` must define a migration class called `CreateStuff`. Two migrations with the same name would necessarily define the same class, which would blow things up. The later class would clobber the methods of the earlier class, or you'd potentially wind up with the first class defining `up/down` and the second class defining `change` yielding some weird undefined behavior. Rails side-steps this mess by enforcing uniqueness on on the migration name.